# AWS Lambda function appending characters in return

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, printing, return, aws-lambda

I have 2 Lambda Functions [A and B]. Function A does a computation and returns 2 strings. Note that I've also tried returning one string. When the function is called alone, the return is the correct expected string.

If I call function A inside function B, the return is the correct string but with characters added to each side.

Function A1 (two strings returned):

```
def handler(event, context):

    strings = {
           "first_string": "This is the first string",
           "second_string": "This is the second string"
    }

    return strings
```

Function A2 (one string returned):

```
def handler(event, context):

    string = "This is a string"

    return string
```

Calling A1 in another Lambda Function:

```
return_strings = functionA1(event, context)
print(return_strings[0])
print(return_strings[1])

>>> 341 #expected This is the first string
>>> 8 #expected This is the second string
```

Calling A2 in another Lambda function:

```
return functionA2(event, context)

>>> b'\"This is a string\"' #expected This is a string
```

Any idea what might be encoded in the returns - is it related to calling from another Lambda function? Invoking A1/A2 on their own gives expected returns.

Thanks!

Comment: You are calling a Lambda function from another Lambda function by using `functionA1(event, context)`? Shouldn't you be using the `Invoke()` command?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am using the Invoke() command - above was just for demo and not precise code

Comment: "Not precise code" does not lend itself to accurate solutions; see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.   The problem is that you seem to be overlooking the fact that everything coming out of a Lambda function invocation should be JSON that needs to be decoded.

Comment: `payload = {}` #blank payload

Comment: `payload['string'] = "This is a string"`

Comment: `lam.invoke(FunctionName='myfunction',
       InvocationType='RequestResponse',
       Payload=json.dumps(payload))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem! Decoding needed before reading the JSON response:

```
load = json.loads(response['Payload'].read().decode("utf-8"))
```